# UNION (5 or more views/tables) Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query that unions multiple views in our SQL Server which is then loaded to PowerBI. The query looks a bit garish so I was hoping to see if there's something that can be done to optimize the query. The code below is just a snippet of the entirety of what I built and none of the fields are the actual field names of our data table.

```
Select
b.SpecID as CaseID,
b.CreateDate,
b.ModifyDate as LastModified,
f.SpecName as Country,
b.CaseDesc,
a.displayname as AssignedTo,
b.PriorCaseMgr as PreviousAsignee,
e.SpecName as CaseSubtype,
b.[ExpectedFinishTime] as [Due Date],
d.refitem as [Status],
c.SpecName as Client,
b.GBC_SM_FFUp as [Number of Follow-ups], 
b.GBC_SMFFUpDate as [Due Date],
b.GBC_SMRemarks as Remarks,
b.Inventory_Status_PH_RefItem as [Inventory Status],
b.Insurer_DataPH_RefItem as Insurer,
b.FirstFollowUp_DataPH as [1st Follow Up Date],
b.SecondFollowUp_DataPH as [2nd Follow Up Date],
b.ThirdFollowUp_DataPH as [3rd Follow Up Date],
b.AdditionalFollowUpDate_DataPH as [Additional Follow Up Dates],
'Survey' as RecordType
from [GBSNightlyBackupReport].[dbo].[CaseAddlDataMemberSupportStaffMovement] as b
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[UserMain] as a on a.[UserID]=b.[CaseMgrID]
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_Client] as c on c.clientID = b.ClientID
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_ReferenceGroupRefGrpItemLanguage] as d on d.refitemid = b.CaseStatusRefID
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_Country] as f on f.SpecID = b.CountryID
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_CaseSubtype] as e on e._SpecID = b.CaseSubTypeID
where (LanguageRefID = 0 and refGrpID=15537532 AND f.SpecID = 408983)OR(LanguageRefID = 0 and refGrpID=15995780 and RefitemID=3453013 AND f.SpecID = 408983)

UNION

Select
b.SpecID as CaseID,
b.CreateDate,
b.ModifyDate as LastModified,
f.SpecName as Country,
b.CaseDesc,
a.displayname as AssignedTo,
b.PriorCaseMgr as PreviousAsignee,
e.SpecName as CaseSubtype,
b.[ExpectedFinishTime] as [Due Date],
d.refitem as [Status],
c.SpecName as Client,
b.GBC_SM_FFUp as [Number of Follow-ups], 
b.GBC_SMFFUpDate as [Due Date],
b.GBC_SMRemarks as Remarks,
b.Inventory_Status_PH_RefItem as [Inventory Status],
b.Insurer_DataPH_RefItem as Insurer,
b.FirstFollowUp_DataPH as [1st Follow Up Date],
b.SecondFollowUp_DataPH as [2nd Follow Up Date],
b.ThirdFollowUp_DataPH as [3rd Follow Up Date],
b.AdditionalFollowUpDate_DataPH as [Additional Follow Up Dates],
'Survey' as RecordType
from [GBSNightlyBackupReport].[dbo].[CaseAddlDataMemberSupportEnrolmentRecon] as b
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[UserMain] as a on a.[UserID]=b.[CaseMgrID]
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_Client] as c on c.clientID = b.ClientID
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_ReferenceGroupRefGrpItemLanguage] as d on d.refitemid = b.CaseStatusRefID
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_Country] as f on f.SpecID = b.CountryID
LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_CaseSubtype] as e on e._SpecID = b.CaseSubTypeID
where (LanguageRefID = 0 and refGrpID=15537532 AND f.SpecID = 408983)OR(LanguageRefID = 0 and refGrpID=15995780 and RefitemID=3453013 AND f.SpecID = 408983)
```

Comment: First thing, unless you are specifically trying to remove duplicates, use `UNION ALL` because it will perform much better

Comment: Secondly, are the queries based on the same tables just with different criteria? Or completely different tables?

Comment: Hi thank you for noticing my post. These are for different tables. I feel using union all is not needed as the records from these tables are already unique

Comment: If they are already unique then you definitely should use `UNION ALL` because it will be much faster (`UNION` is for deduplicating).

Comment: And the queries are for different tables, then you have no choice but to use union as you are already doing... I mean how else could you imagine simplifying it?

Comment: I saw some solutions where they used the joins not within the queries but after unioning it. I don't know if that's more efficient or not.

Comment: They only way you can use joins is if you have common tables... which you you said you didn't have. If you do have common tables, then yes, you can probably use your `UNION ALL` in a subquery and then join the common tables after that. Very hard to know without a proper [mre].

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for taking the time in answering my queries and by the way, the UNION ALL did alleviate the load time from 1 hour and 12 minutes down to 41 minutes. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: try also to change the join "LEFT JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_Country] as f on f.SpecID = b.CountryID". In the where condition you are always asking f.SpecID to match some values: I would test "INNER JOIN [GBSNightlyBackupReport].dbo.[_Country] as f on f.SpecID = b.CountryID and f.SpecID = 408983". In the example above you should have the same output and I would expect a better performance: inner joins are faster than left joins and in this case inner join is not selecting less records.

Comment: If it's optimization you're truly after- then are the tables in the views sargable and can they be indexed for that query?  If you don't like using a verbose amount of code in Power BI to select 5-6 unioned views then an option is creating a stored procedure to simplify calling it, ex .`EXEC dbo.myproc`.

Comment: Hello. Yes I get the inner join part and thanks for pointing out the redundancy on my part. As for creating indexes and stored procedures, these are elevated privileges I do not have.